# `docker pull` returns `denied: access forbidden` from private gitlab registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` which is going to be implemented `FROM` a private registry's image. I build this file without any problem with `Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802` and `docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown`, but in another machine which has `Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737` and `docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21`, the `docker-compose build` returns:

```
FROM my.private.gitlab.registry:port/image:tag
http://my.private.gitlab.registry:port/v2/docker/image/manifests/tag: denied: access forbidden
```

`docker pull my.private.gitlab.registry:port/image:tag` returns the same.

Notice that I tried to get `my.private.registry:port/image:tag` and `http://my.private.registry:port/v2/docker/image/manifests/tag` has been catched.

Comment: If this is a authenticated registry then you need to run `docker login <regitsryurl>` on the machine where you are building this. This only needs to be done once

Comment: @TarunLalwani, it returned `Unauthorized: authentication required`. Maybe it's related to my permissions on gitlab. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, you've pointed to the exact cause. Please post it as an answer, so I can approve.

Comment: i am still searching for answer on this

Comment: Doesn't this answer work for you @ShikharChaudhary ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422186/1626977

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar Yeah this worked for me. In added the private repo in daemon.json unauth registry.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If this is an authenticated registry, then you need to run `docker login <registryurl>` on the machine where you are building this.

This only needs to be done once per host. The command then caches the auth in a file

```
$ cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "......="
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One note on this: make sure that `<registryurl>` is `my.private.registry:port/path/to/repo`. `docker login my.private.registry` did not give me sufficient permissions to pull the image.

Comment: As @JacobStern mentioned it's important to use the full path, but also: it's important to add the version! So it must be: `my.private.registry/path/to/repo:version`

Comment: what to put in auth .... ?

Comment: readers pay attention to the port, it really matters if docker image name contains the port you must specify the port while login too `docker login <registry-url>:<registry-port>` and if no port is in docker image name then only `docker login <registry-url>`

Answer (score 10):

A login did not fix the problem for me. This may be specific to Mac, but just in case here is the [Git issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6832)

My comment on it:

Also experiencing this issue.

### Dockerfile:

`FROM <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest`

### CLI

Both commands fail without a login to the private registry (expected)

```
    $ docker-compose up
    Building app
    Step 1/2 : FROM <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: Get https://<insert_private_registry>/v2/test-image/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden

    $ docker pull <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    Error response from daemon: Get https://<insert_private_registry>/test-image/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
```

After logging in, a `docker pull ...` works while the `docker-compose up` fails to pull the image:

```sh
    $ docker login <insert_private_registry>
    Username: <insert>
    Password: <insert>
    Login Succeeded

    $ docker-compose up
    Building app
    Step 1/2 : FROM <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: Get https://<insert_private_registry>/v2/test-image/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden

    $ docker pull <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    latest: Pulling from <insert_private_image_path>/test-image
    ...
    Status: Downloaded newer image for <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
```

### Current Solution

Our current workaround is to explicitly pull the image prior to running the docker-compose containers:

```sh
    docker pull <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    latest: Pulling from <insert_private_image_path>/test-image
    ...
    Status: Downloaded newer image for <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest

    $ docker-compose up
    Building app
    Step 1/2 : FROM <insert_private_registry>/test-image:latest
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I notice your URL scheme uses the http protocol - Docker needs to be configured to allow insecure registries.

Create or modify your `daemon.json` (required in one of the following locations):

Linux: `/etc/docker/`

Windows: `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\`

With the contents:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "my.private.gitlab.registry:port" ]
}
```

Then restart Docker (not just the terminal session) and try again.

Once you've logged in with:

```
docker login my.private.gitlab.registry:port
```

As per [tarun-lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani)'s answer, this should then add the auth into the config, for future use (`docker pull`'s etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In my case on Linux I can fix this error by adding sudo to my docker-compose up command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In my case docker image name contains port `reg.mygitlab.com:443/internal/ci-docker-base:python3` so that i need to to do was `docker login reg.mygitlab.com:443` you see the `433` there that is important it sims like later on when docker is trying to pull images it will use the exact name which contains port too